# What have I got wrong with these code blocks?

Tags: objective-c, swift

I'm attempting to use Tony Million's Reachability within a new Swift based app.  I have it implemented in another app I wrote in Obj C, but I'm having issues with getting the proper syntax in Swift.  The code blocks are as follows:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    messageText.text = ""

    var reach: Reachability = Reachability(hostName: "www.apple.com")

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "reachabilityChanged", name: kReachabilityChangedNotification, object: nil)


    reach.reachableBlock = Reachability()
    {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            self.messageText.text = "Enter search criteria...";
            })
    }

    reach.unreachableBlock = Reachability()
    {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            self.messageText.text = "Attempting to contact network...";
            })
    }

    reach.startNotifier()

}
```

AND

```
func reachabilityChanged(note: NSNotification)
{

    var reach: Reachability = Reachability()
    if(reach.isReachable())
    {
        messageText.text = "Enter search criteria...";
    }
    else
    {
        messageText.text = "Attempting to contact network...";
    }

}
```

My issues are first, my "blocks" for "reachable" and "unreachable" are not the correct syntax and I'm at a loss for what is the proper syntax for these blocks.  My second issue is with the "reachabilityChanged" function.  I get an error stating "-[_TtC9icdDRPlus20SearchViewController reachabilityChanged]: unrecognized selector sent to instance" which I'm again at a loss.  Condsider my Obj C code as follows:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
NSString *popUpShownOnce = @"YES";
NSInteger swipeCount = 0;
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:popUpShownOnce forKey:@"popDisplayed"];
[defaults setInteger:swipeCount forKey:@"showswipearrows"];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(reachabilityChanged:)
                                             name:kReachabilityChangedNotification
                                           object:nil];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];

Reachability * reach = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostname:@"somesite.com"];

reach.reachableBlock = ^(Reachability * reachability)
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        searchForText.placeholder = @"Enter search criteria...";
    });
};

reach.unreachableBlock = ^(Reachability * reachability)
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        searchForText.placeholder = @"Attempting to contact network...";
    });
};

[reach startNotifier];
}

-(void)reachabilityChanged:(NSNotification*)note
{
Reachability * reach = [note object];

if([reach isReachable])
{
    searchForText.placeholder = @"Enter search criteria...";
}
else
{
    searchForText.placeholder = @"Attempting to contact network...";
}
}
```

Assistance is greatly appreciated.  The questions are as follows:
1.  What is the proper translation for the reachable and unreachable blocks from Obj C to Swift?
2.  If my addObserver call is correct, why might I get the unrecognized selector error?  If not correct, what is the proper call?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax for closures is `{ (<params>) -> <return type> in <statements> }`:

```
reach.reachableBlock = { (reachability) in
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        self.messageText.text = "Enter search criteria...";
        })
}
```

With `NSNotificationCenter`, looks like you missed the colon in the selector argument:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "reachabilityChanged:", name: kReachabilityChangedNotification, object: nil)
```

Comment: That's almost it.  The closures are compiling now and the selector now has the ":" but apparently my "reachabilityChanged" method is still incorrect.  Any ideas?  I'm getting EXC_BAD_Access at SCNetworkReachabilitySetCallback(self.reachabilityRef, NULL, NULL); in the Reachability class

Comment: That function is a method on the view controller, and not in the global score, right?

Answer (score 2):

Your error after making the changes that @Austin recommended is that self.reachabilityRef in SCNetworkReachabilitySetCallback is NULL.

try:

```
func reachabilityChanged(note: NSNotification!) {

    var reach: Reachability! = Reachability(reachabilityRef: note.object as SCNetworkReachability)

    if(reach.isReachable()) {
        messageText.text = "Enter search criteria...";
    } else {
        messageText.text = "Attempting to contact network...";
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

It would seem that SCNetworkReachability is not currently fully working with Swift: according to this: https://twitter.com/marksands/status/474717606004273152

Comment: That gave me the following--->   Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SCNetworkReachability", referenced from:
      __TFC9icdDRPlus20SearchViewController19reachabilityChangedfS0_FGSQCSo14NSNotification_T_ in SearchViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: can you try building it onto a device?

Comment: Unfortunately, not at this time.  I haven't updated the device yet and was attempting to get a working prototype on the simulator first.  It's fairly frustrating to have a working Obj C implementation and being unable to get a similar implementation working with Swift.  I can see past my lack of knowledge of Swift at this point.  I'm mostly confused at why an Obj C project compiles and runs fine on the sim but this Swift project doesn't, especially since it's a pretty generic prototype-that is checking for connectivity.

Comment: I just came across this twitter post: https://twitter.com/marksands/status/474717606004273152

hopefully Apple will have this sorted out for us soon.

Comment: Nice!  Well I can see the tweet, but no supporting link in the tweet for further information.

Comment: Scratch that!  Just confirmed, it is a reported item.  I wish I could vote answered to both, but I can't it seems.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work like this:

```
var reachability: Reachability?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Setup reachability
    reachability = Reachability(hostName: "www.google.com")
    reachability!.reachableBlock = { (reach) in
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            self.titleLabel.attributedText = Utilities.myAttributedText("Online", mySize: 18, myFont: "HelveticaNeue", myColor: UIColor.whiteColor())
            self.titleLabel.sizeToFit()
            })
    }
    reachability!.unreachableBlock = { (reach) in
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            self.titleLabel.attributedText = Utilities.myAttributedText("Offline", mySize: 18, myFont: "HelveticaNeue", myColor: UIColor.whiteColor())
            self.titleLabel.sizeToFit()
            })
    }
    reachability!.startNotifier()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me:

```
 //Reachability
    myReachabilityInstance = Reachability(hostName: "www.google.com")
    myReachabilityInstance?.reachableOnWWAN = false
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "reachabilityDidChangeMethod", name: kReachabilityChangedNotification, object: nil)
    myReachabilityInstance?.startNotifier()
```